# Tangent equation at a point of a algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have following alleged simple question: Let $ 0= f(x,y)$ be a equation of a algebraic curve and $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point belonging to it. I'm looking for an explicit (no by using examples) proof that the tangent equation in $(x_0,y_0)$ is givven by $\frac{df(x_0,y_0)}{dx}(x-x_0) + \frac{df(x_0,y_0)}{dy} (y-y_0) =0$.

WR

Karl

Comment: What is your definition of tangent?

Comment: @Χpẘ I cannot make head nor tail of your comment.  The fact that $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$ certainly does not imply that its partial derivatives are $0$.  Take for instance $f(x,y) = y - x^2$ and the point $(0,0)$.  $f(0,0) = 0$, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = 1$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent The equation of the curve is $f(x,y)=0$. I presume that means $\forall x, \forall y$. Is there some other way to interpret $f(x,y)=0$?

Comment: @Χpẘ $f$ is some polynomial in 2 variables.  The curve is given by its zero set, i.e., $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{A}^2 : f(x,y) = 0\}$.  In the example I gave above, the curve would be solutions of the equation $0 = y - x^2$, a parabola.  This is a standard way to specify a curve; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve) or [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=IdARBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false), for example.  I doubt very much that the OP means that $f$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thanks for the explanation and the links. Just to double check, does $f(x,y)=0$ tell us anything different than just $f(x,y)$?